# Numeric result blank for T-SQL union

Tags: sql, t-sql, union

I'm writing a Transact-SQL query which involves several UNIONS where, where the datatype of the second column is an int. The datatype of the first column is a varchar.

Here's an example of the issue I'm having. In the SQL below, the query won't run because it won't let me leave the second column blank for that last SELECT statement. I put a blank varchar there (' ') but it requires an int, so am I forced to put in a dummy value like 0?

```
SELECT product, price
  FROM tableA    
UNION ALL    
SELECT '', SUM(price)
  FROM tableB    
UNION ALL    
SELECT '', ''
  FROM tableC
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this query? It seems like you're trying to coerce SQL into outputting it's results in a specific format for reporting. Further, your DB design looks like it may have been created for this as well. If that's the case, it's a bad practice to get into.

Comment: That's pretty accurate, I'm trying to form the output into a specific format. What's the best practice way to do this?

Comment: Formatting of data should be done on the front end. A database is there to store and retrieve data. Tying it to the formatting of the data can cause all sorts of problems. How specifically you solve this problem would depend on what your front-end is (Crystal Reports, SSRS, a web page...)

Comment: Oh, yes I see what you're saying, maybe I misunderstood you. I'm often asked to write reports directly out of the database for information my company doesn't have time to develop a front-end solution for. I agree with you though that would be the best way.

Comment: In that case, I'd still make very certain that your display logic doesn't get intermingled with the actual database design/code. Use PRINT or display rows as needed, but make sure it's well insulated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not select null and cast it to a number when really necessary?

```
SELECT product, price
FROM tableA

UNION ALL

SELECT '', SUM(price)
FROM tableB

UNION ALL

SELECT 'space', NULL
FROM tableC
```

Comment: In SQL Server, NULL still needs to be cast/converted to the data type.  By default, NULL is INT.

Comment: The following works fine for me in SQL 2008: SELECT 1, 'a' UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Is it documented somewhere that `NULL` is `int` by default? I remember trying to find out that recently for some purpose. `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(NULL, 'BaseType')` returns `NULL`. On the other hand, NULL has never caused any incompatibility issues when used as a place-holder for omitted columns in my UNIONed selects, which seems more or less consistent with what SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY returns.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying null : 
`SELECT 'space', null`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product, price
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT '', SUM(price)
FROM tableB
UNION ALL
SELECT 'space', NULL
FROM tableC
```

or

```
SELECT product, price
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT '', SUM(price)
FROM tableB
UNION ALL
SELECT 'space', 0 -- These are just two hardcoded values, so why are we selecting from a table?
FROM tableC
```

or

```
SELECT product, price
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT '', SUM(price)
FROM tableB
UNION ALL
SELECT 'space', 0
```